# MVC 2 JSON equivalent to FormCollection

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a JSON equivalent for FormCollection form as a POST action parameter?  I have a dynamically generated number of fields that I need to post back via JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply serialize a [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) from your FormCollection, using the `new NameValueCollection(NameValueCollection)` [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s711zk3.aspx). That is all a [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx) is, after all.